# Are IPO lockup shares counted when calculating eps?

Tags: ipo, earnings-per-share

For example,

- Company XYZ has an IPO on January 1st
- They offer 10 million shares
- 90 million shares are still held by insiders
- The lockup lasts until June 1st
- They report earnings of $100m for Q1 on May 10th

What would the EPS be for Q1? 
Would it be

- $1 ($100m / 100m shares)
- $10 ($100m / 10m shares)

Comment: Are the 90M shares actually _held by insiders_ (i.e. issued and beneficially owned by directors/owners/founders) or are they simply [_unissued_](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/unissued-shares) (aka "held in treasury")?

Comment: I suppose that’s part of the question. When trying to find the eps of BYND for example, is it based off the total shares or the publicly available shares?

Comment: AFAIK, it's based off the _owned_ (but not necessarily publicly-available) shares. As you say, the question becomes whether the 90M shares in your example are _owned_ or not.